# com_jea map - помогите?

Tags: php, javascript

Проблема в ниже приведенном коде не понимаю где именно находится ошибка.

```
$script = <<<EOD
function initMap(myLatlng) {

$('longitude').setProperty('value', myLatlng.lng());
$('latitude').setProperty('value', myLatlng.lat());

var options = {
  zoom : $zoom,
  center : myLatlng,
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map($("map_canvas"), options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map, 
    title: '$markerLabel',
    draggable: true,
    cursor: 'move'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(mouseEvent) {
    $('longitude').setProperty('value', mouseEvent.latLng.lng());
    $('latitude').setProperty('value', mouseEvent.latLng.lat());
});
}

window.addEvent("domready", function(){
var longitude = {$this->row->longitude};
var latitude  = {$this->row->latitude};

if( longitude != 0 && latitude != 0 ) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    initMap(myLatlng);
} else {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var opts = {'address':'$address', 'language':'$lang', 'region':'$region'};
    geocoder.geocode(opts, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myLatlng = results[0].geometry.location;
            initMap(myLatlng);
        }
    });
}
});

window.addEvent("unload", function(){

});
EOD;
```

Comment: И в чем ваш вопрос? Уточните, в чем именно заключается ваша проблема. Посетите страницу ["как задавать вопросы"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), чтобы понять как следует оформлять вопросы.

Comment: вопрос заключается в том что где находится ошибка в данном коде т.к сам я не нашел ее указывает он на var longitude = {$this->row->longitude}; но в этой строчке точно нет ошибки

Comment: Прежде всего вам следует прочесть [это](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). К сожалению эта статья еще не переведена на русский, но Гугл-переводчик вам в помощь.

Comment: его и так тут вроде мало вам не кажется ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего ошибка в строках

```
var longitude = {$this->row->longitude};
var latitude  = {$this->row->latitude};
```

если переменные `{$this->row->longitude}` или `{$this->row->latitude}` являются пустрой строкой, то сгенерированный javascript код будет выглядеть так:

```
var longitude = ;
var latitude  = ;
```

и вызовете ошибку "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'"